# how to integrate "sign in with twitter" feature with API's such as MGTwitterengine in MAC OS X with OAuth

Tags: macos, cocoa, twitter, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am new to Cocoa and wanted to develop an app which can use Sign in with twitter feature in order to authenticate user. There are API's and sample code for IOS but for Mac there are few and they are limited to sending tweets. Where as i want to open webview where user can enter twitter credentials and allow the application and thus i can proceed to other webpage.

I will be very thankful if someone can help  me out. I will be really greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got the solution to this twitter integration in MAC OS.

the below link on github does the same.

https://github.com/yourhead/OAuth_ObjC_Test_App